# Invoke Workflow VS Launch Workflow Interactive in UIPath

Tags: uipath

What are the difference between **Invoke Workflow** and **Launch Workflow Interactive** activity in UIPath?

Answer (score 0):

Invoke workflow with Isolated property checked, works in the same way as Launch workflow Interactive. Meaning they run in separate windows session. Launch workflow interactive forces the workflow to run in a separate windows process. I have used both the activities and seems like Invoke workflow sometimes doesn't run in a separate process. But the Launch workflow interactive definitely runs in separate process.

Comment: Which one is the best to use? Can I always use Launch Workflow Interactive?

Comment: Depends on your requirement. Please find the below posts for more information :
https://forum.uipath.com/t/launch-workflow-interactive-and-secure-string-doesnt-work/17957/2                                                               https://forum.uipath.com/t/launch-workflow-interactive-and-secure-string-doesnt-work/17957/2